# Properly Reload div via Ajax - Script disappears

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have my **header.php** containing a button which triggers the sidebar menu to appear. Button and sidebar are visible only for **logged in** users. At the end of this block there is a little piece of code that adds the class "active" to my sidebar for making it visible. It's something like:

```
<div id="header">
<!-- if is_user_logged_in -->
<a id="menu-toggle" href="#" type="button">
  <i class="sprite-t-toggle-side"></i>
</a>
<!-- sidebar menu-->
<div id="sidebar-wrapper"><!-- menu content --></div>
<script>
   var $menu = $("#sidebar-wrapper");
   $("#menu-toggle").on("click", function(e) {
     e.preventDefault(), 
     $menu.toggleClass("active");
   });
</script>
</div>
```

Now, I make my users login via AJAX and once they're logged I just refresh my header block for displaying button and sidebar. I use this line of code to do so in my AJAX success:

```
success: function(data){
              if (data.loggedin == true){
              $("#header").load(location.href + " #header");
  }
}
```

Until here everything is fine, **users are logged** and **button is displayed** but when I click on it nothing happens. Sidebar won't appear and If I look at the code my  little function, at the end of header, is missing. Otherwise, If I reload the whole page it works.
What's happening? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: So it is running the $("#header").load(location.href + " #header");

Comment: yes. That is working @askingquestions

Comment: Try removing e.preventDefault(), Is that needed?

Comment: @askingquestions Thank you for your answer but it's still not working. My script once the #header block is refreshed it's missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why reload the entire header. Why not just grab the logged in part of it

I think problem is that you are reloading the entire `#header` you need to just reload part of it.

---

`$("#header").load(location.href + " #header");` <- this will replace all html in 
the `#header`

```
<div id="header">
<div id="loadajax"></div> <!-- Put loaded ajax in here --->
<!-- if is_user_logged_in -->
<a id="menu-toggle" href="#" type="button">
  <i class="sprite-t-toggle-side"></i>
</a>
<!-- sidebar menu-->
<div id="sidebar-wrapper"><!-- menu content --></div>
<script>
function runMenu() {
   var $menu = $("#sidebar-wrapper");
   $("#menu-toggle").on("click", function(e) {
     e.preventDefault(), 
     $menu.toggleClass("active");
   });
}
runMenu();
</script>
</div>
```

---

```
success: function(data){
   if (data.loggedin == true){
      $("#loadajax").load(location.href + " #header");
      runMenu();
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok cool, now I see the script in my code. I've refreshed just that part. The problem is that `id="menu-toggle"` seems to not recognise the associated script. It's like just a link without javascript.

Comment: Yes that is because your javascript is running on the load of the page. I changed my post to fix that.

Comment: I'm glad I could help!